# PHPDesktop running all the time

Tags: php, phpdesktop

I'm using PHPDesktop for my project. I need to make sure its running all the time at background even though they have closed it. Something like chrome background service. How to make it happen . Any suggestion will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

HStart lets you run app hidden (commercial): http://www.ntwind.com/software/hstart.html

Another solution is to use AutoHotkey (free): https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/53974-start-an-application-hidden-from-cmdexe/

If you google "start app hidden" you may find more.